# Unity Texture2D.Resize() yielding empty texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resize, texture2d

I'm trying to resize (scale down) a texture2d before compressing it and sending over the network but the resulting texture2d is empty (it just loads as solid gray). am I using `tex.Resize(800, 600, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);` incorrectly?

```
[Client]
    public void PrepareServerData(Texture2D texToSend, string typeToSend)
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoResizeTex(texToSend));
        StartCoroutine(DoGetTexToBytes(texToSend));

        playerObj.texWidth = texToSend.width;
        playerObj.texHeight = texToSend.height;
        playerObj.texFormat = texToSend.format;
        playerObj.tranX = tran.x;
        playerObj.tranY = tran.y;
        playerObj.tranZ = tran.z;
        playerObj.type = typeToSend;
        Player_ID id = GetComponent<Player_ID>();
        playerObj.id = id.MakeUniqueIdentity();
        playerObj.strength = strengthToSend;
        playerObj.hitpoints = hitPointsToSend;

        Network_Serializer serialize = GetComponent<Network_Serializer>();
        byte[] bytes = serialize.ObjectToByteArray(playerObj);

        StartCoroutine(Network_Transmitter.instance.DoSendBytes(0, bytes));
    }

    IEnumerator DoGetTexToBytes(Texture2D tex)
    {
        byte[] texBytes = tex.GetRawTextureData();                      // convert texture to raw bytes
        byte[] compressedTexBytes = lzip.compressBuffer(texBytes, 9);   // compress texture byte array
        playerObj.texBytes = compressedTexBytes;                        // set compressed bytes to player object

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        GameObject infoDisplayText = GameObject.Find("InfoDisplay");
        infoDisplayText.GetComponent<Text>().text += "Bytes to send : " + playerObj.texBytes.Length + "\n";
    }

    IEnumerator DoResizeTex(Texture2D tex)
    {
        tex.Resize(800, 600, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
        tex.Apply();

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I am currently also digging through texture resize in Unity and Texture.Resize I found only resizes the container (the array of data) of the texture, it does not use content but has to be filled-- in my opinion it suggests something else, just like you expected.
Looks like texture resizing is not a feature implemented in C# in Unity and has to be done per pixel by iterating and processing data.

Not comfortable and unfortunately very slow.
There is an asset available that fills the gap (Texture Adjustments).

Comment: "has to be done per pixel by iterating and processing data" Think about it, what other possible way could it be done? Scaling from one container size to another changes the number of pixels. Unity can't possibly know what pixels should be removed (when scaling down) or added (when scaling up.) A scaling algorithm would be needed, such as nearest neighbor, bilinear, etc. which you will need to implement yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, that only resizes the container. To scale the texture you can use `Graphics.ConvertTexture(source, destination)`, where resolution of `destination` is your target resolution.

For example:

```
IEnumerator DoScaleTex(Texture2D tex)
{
    Texture2D scaled = new Texture2D(800, 600, TextureFormat.RGB24, true);
    Graphics.ConvertTexture(tex, scaled);
    tex = scaled;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

Comment: From the following issue: https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/textures-become-gray-when-they-are-converted-with-graphics-dot-converttexture:

ConvertTexture works on the GPU side only, it does not set the proper CPU side pixel data. As a result, any pixel reading functionality gives invalid results (e.g. GetPixels, EncodeToPNG, etc). You should use Texture2D.ReadPixels to transfer pixels to the CPU side in another Texture2D and and then perform any pixel access operations on that new Texture.

Comment: To add further info to what @Eiron points out, ConvertTexture also has significant API limitations. E.g. it's not supported for DX9 and Mac+OpenGL. You'll need to use  SystemInfo.copyTextureSupport to see if it's even supported on the hardware it's executed on.